# Non-medical N95 / KN95 / FFP2 masks, beards, shaving, Chol Ha'moed, and the Omer

Tags: halacha, health-safety-shmira, chol-hamoed, shaving, covid19-pandemic

## Background information

There's no longer a shortage of non-medical N95 / FFP2 masks.  Anyone who wants enhanced protection against COVID can now get some.  Despite some rumors to the contrary, these masks can be easy to breathe through and reasonably comfortable.  I often wear one, even at the supermarket.

If you'd like, you can view [links to vendors of N95 / FFP2 masks](https://www.reddit.com/r/Masks4All/comments/lu2xwr/fresh_for_march_2021_a_new_mask_review_thread/gpbt2g8/) in various countries.

Beard hair can cause an N95 / KN95 / FFP2 mask to leak.  This means that the mask may not work as well.  In fact, in such a case, it might provide you with little or no protection at all.  [(Source.)](https://www.reddit.com/r/Masks4All/comments/ls1eh3/halfface_respirators_for_bearded_men_3m_6000_vs/gorqh02/)  Even a day or two worth of stubble can start to reduce protection.  [(Source.)](https://blogs.cdc.gov/niosh-science-blog/2017/11/02/noshave/)

If you really don't want to shave, one possible workaround is to apply an [under-mask beard cover](https://www.reddit.com/r/Masks4All/comments/jvccmm/method_to_pass_fit_test_with_beard_singh_thattha/).  But it may be safer and more elegant just to shave.

## My questions

A.)  If you're planning to wear an N95 / KN95 / FFP2 mask around town, can you shave during Ḥol Ha'moed?

B.)  How about during the Omer?

Comment: See Radvaz cited in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95530/13438).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten permission from my rabbi in the past to shave on Chol HaMoed and during the Omer for purposes of appearing professional at work. I strongly suspect that there's room to be lenient for the purpose of enhanced pandemic protection. If this issue affects you, I recommend [asking your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).