# What are the parameters of hachnassat orchim?

Tags: halacha, torts-damages, hachnasat-orchim-guests

I have always believed in having a home open to guests, whether for Shabbat, hagim or for their secular needs, involving guests sleeping over.

However, recently my guests have inadvertently caused me damages that ran into a lot of expense for which I would not charge them.

This makes me feel that I have to become much more limited in how I have guests or not at all (to sleep over).
So I'm curious what the halacha has to say about this.

Comment: "for which I would not charge them" Why won't you charge them if they damaged you?

Comment: Why would someone vote to close as opinion based on a question asking what the halacha has to say?

Comment: If a guest damaged something, ask them to pay for it.  If they refuse, take them to beis din.

Comment: janet, welcome to Mi Yodeya! It seems to me that this question is more about mussar/ethics/charachter-development than halacha. It sounds like you don't want to diminish your act of kindness and/or damage a social relationship by introducing liability and money into it, but that maintaining that standard of pure kindness and/or preserving the relationship thus makes you less likely to extend invitations in the future. So, it seems like the conflict is between internal values more than halachot. Does that sound right? If so, I recommend that you [edit] the question to make this more clear.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27260/at-what-cost-must-one-perform-a-mitzvah

Answer (score 3):

I found a [nice essay on Hachnassat Orchim](http://www.cckollel.org/html/parsha/bereishis/vayera-2002.html) that mentions the following:

> If a loss or any damage will result from hosting a particular guest
>   one would not be obligated to host him [Orech Maisharim 17-2].