# What are the limits of hospitality?

Tags: vayera, parashat-chaye-sara, shoftim--book-of, hachnasat-orchim-guests

Hospitality is valued very highly in Judaism, witness Abraham [Gen. 18:1-5], Lot [Gen. 19:1-8], Laban [Gen. 24:28–32], Manoah [Judges 13:15-16] or the unhappy matter of the concubine of Gibeah [Judges 19:23–24].

The Talmud says that there are six matters for which a person enjoys the profits in this world, while the principal remains for him for the World-to-Come, and hospitality is the first one listed [Shabbat 127a].

But hospitality has limits: (1) God did not look kindly on Lot offering his daughters to protect his guests [Midrash Tanhuma, Vayera 12]; (2) priorities must be set clearly (story of woman offering what little bread she had to comfort a stranger during a siege when there wasn't enough for her own family [Lam. R. 4:13]; and (3) possible strain on the family if the wife or children are not as eager as the husband to welcome guests [Bava Metzia 87a, Ber. 10b].

But I could not find anything in the Sources about **the biggest deterrent of all to hospitality: Security.**  It could be very dangerous to welcome in your house a stranger who may turn against you.  Is there anything in halacha about this?  (I an sure I don't need to dwell on the current relevance of this issue.)

**Added**:  [The other article](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45205/what-are-the-parameters-of-hachnassat-orchim) concludes: "If a loss or any damage will result from hosting a particular guest one would not be obligated to host him [Orech Maisharim 17-2]." That is not an answer to my question. You don't know beforehand whether you will suffer a loss or not.  I am bothered by the fact that I did not find even a simple "just be careful" in the Sources.

Comment: 1. Correct me if I'm wrong, but hospitality is not on the list of the Mitzvos. G-d didn't say "open your house to strangers". 2. Another deterrent would be poverty - spending too much on hospitality. 3. Security is a very ill-defined term, and in many cases it overrides many real Mitzvos (Pikuach Nefesh?).

Comment: I am bothered by the fact that I did not find even a simple "just be careful" in the Sources.

Comment: @doubleAA -- "If a loss or any damage will result from hosting a particular guest one would not be obligated to host him [Orech Maisharim 17-2]."  That is not an answer to my question.  You don't know beforehand whether it will or won't.

Comment: My Google-fu seems to be a bit off now (or I don't remeber the wording exactly) but there is a phrase that goes something like "Kabdeihu Vechashdeihu", which means that while you honor someone, you still need to be suspect (as needed). Is used in context to having a guest.

Comment: It appears that you can add this phrase to just any Mitzvah - "just be careful" when building a Succah, "just be careful" when lightning Shabbos candles, "just be careful" when fasting for 25 hours, "just be careful" when marrying someone you don't really know, etc.

Comment: @DoubleAA -- Please respond to my comment to you.  This is not a duplicate question.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi I'm not quite sure what youre pointing out to me. The questions seem to overlap significantly.

Comment: @DoubleAA -- I wrote that the "duplicate" says: "If a loss or any damage will result from hosting a particular guest one would not be obligated to host him [Orech Maisharim 17-2]." That is not an answer to my question. You don't know beforehand whether it will or won't.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what youre pointing out to me. The questions seem to overlap significantly.

Comment: @Maurice Mizrahi - how is the mitzvah of hachnasat orchim unique in terms of security? Inviting another into your home is not necessarily more dangerous than doing kiddush levana in a dark alley, or walking across a busy street. As with any life situation - use your common sense.