# What's the minimum mezuzot required for financial hardship?

Tags: halacha, money, mezuzah

What is the minimal amount of mezuzot required when one factors in financial hardship?

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/902318/rabbi-ezra-schwartz/life-in-the-heights-xi-overview-of-mezuza-issues/

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'financial hardship'? Why would Mezuzah be any different than financial considerations for any other positive commandment? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27260/at-what-cost-must-one-perform-a-mitzvah

Comment: An obligated doorway only needs one, even if you are very wealthy.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin That would depend on whether every door has an obligation of mezuzah. So he's either asking how much you have to spend when there's an obligation, in which case it's a duplicate, or he's asking what doors are obligated in mezuzah, in which case it is unclear because he doesn't state that in the question.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin That's where [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4674/voting-to-reopen-in-order-to-close-for-a-different-reason) comes into play.

Comment: @shmuel there's no need to speculate. If he means something different than what he wrote he should edit. We shouldn't open a question and answer it based on a guess that he didn't mean what he said.